# Reflect the changes made in one table in sql to reflect automatically on another table

Tags: sql

I have created a table in SQL by copying data from another table in a different database. How can I make the changes made in the old table get reflected in the new table automatically?

Comment: The simple solution is to not store data elements twice.  Use a query to fetch the data you want from a normalized schema so the data is ALWAYS in synch.

Comment: As mentioned above no need to create duplicate tables. Else Create a trigger on old table for syncing changes.

Comment: Or create a view. Will always be up-to-date.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, Could you elaborate on that please. I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Trigger function to reflect the changes.

Refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table).

Given that you have access over the First table, Trigger would work fine.